# Primefaces themeSwitcher selectedTheme

Tags: jsf, primefaces, themes

I used for setting Primefaces themeSwitcher component as in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml).List is coming but themeSwitcher value is null.Here the codes

```
 <h:panelGrid id="themeForm" columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{res['ko.settings.tabThemeSettings.themeName']}" />
    <p:outputPanel>
            <p:themeSwitcher id="basic" 
                             style="width:165px"
                             value="#{settingsBean.selectedTheme}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.themes}" 
                                   var="theme"
                                   itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" />
            </p:themeSwitcher>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:commandButton id="themeButton"
                 value="#{res['ko.settings.tabThemeSettings.themeButton']}"
                 icon="#{res['ko.saveIcon']}"
                 actionListener="#{settingsBean.saveTheme}" 
                 process="@this" update="basic"/>
 </h:panelGrid>
```

And in the backing bean with getter and setter ;

```
private Theme selectedTheme;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you use `value="#{settingsBean.themes}"` for list theme value, and use `value="#{settingsBean.selectedTheme}"` for getting value from list of theme, but you did not have a **converter** to convert your theme.